# Jackson, read/write nested properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

Using Jackson, I'm creating a Json object like this:

```
{"A": {
    "B": {
        "C": {
            "D": 1
        }
    }
}}
```

with the next code

```
ObjectNode rootNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
ObjectNode aNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
ObjectNode bNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
ObjectNode cNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
cNode.put("D", 1);
bNode.set("C", cNode);
aNode.set("B", bNode);
rootNode.set("A", aNode);
```

Is there a more simple way to create it? something like:

```
ObjectNode rootNode = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
rootNode.set("A/B/C/D",1);
```

Also reading a similar object is there a simply way to get the value of "D"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can create nested structures with this:

```
ObjectNode root = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
root.with("A").with("B").with("C").put("D", 1);
```

Comment: This is nice(r). You should probably quote the API about its limitations.

Comment: Thanks. Just a small update `put` is deprecated - you can use `set(String fieldName, JsonNode value)` instead

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can do do it like below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class TestJackson {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode node = mapper.readValue("{\"A\": {\"B\": { \"C\": {\"D\": 1 } }}}", JsonNode.class);
}
}
```

Comment: And then read the value with
        node.get("A").get("B").get("C").get("D").asInt()

Comment: You can read the value with node.findValues("D").get(0).asInt() as well. ;)